# Play/Stop button with Jquery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have to embed jquery slider in my webpage, given at http://jqueryui.com/slider/
I can be embedded easily. Problem is that i have to play/stop slider when i click play/stop button in front of slider. How it can be done in jS/JQuery. Slider should move ahead after 1/2 seconds as in Video Players (I don't have to made video player, just trying to explore my problem). Please help how it can be done?

Comment: you u put up a link or jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea what you are saying, but I will try something...

jquery slider can be disbled, it's one of the options: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-disabled

you can reset it by setting the value to 0

in case the play/stop button actually on top of the slider, you can just jquery to prevent event bubbling: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

in case you want to handle value change programmatically and user dragging differently: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/slider-event-originalevent

hope this help